# Return with changing number in source url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

When user visits:

```
/profile.php?mode=viewprofile&u=[NUMBER FROM 1 TO 4000]
```

I want nginx to return:

```
/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=[SAME NUMBER]
```

How can I do it? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to match `/profile.php` and `mode=viewprofile` which is not trivial `nginx`. There are a number of ways to achieve it.

You could replicate the `location ~\.php$` block and add the conditional redirection there:

```
location = /profile.php {
    if ($arg_mode = viewprofile) {
        return 301 /memberlist.php?$args;
    }
    ... # add location ~\.php$ stuff here
}
```

Alternatively, check the $request_uri (which contains the original URI including query string), early in the `server` block:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^/profile\.php\?mode=viewprofile&") {
    return 301 /memberlist.php?$args;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` statement.